# Uploading big files with .net core 2.1 and Azure

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core-2.1, azure-blob-storage

Can you please help, have the next problem:

Can't upload a big file(~200 MB) to the website. Using .net core 2.1 project and Azure blob. So find that I should set up

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="100000"/>
</system.web>
```

and

```
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
```

in web.config, but couldn't set it up, so find that i could do it in applicationhost.config

After that in works in local machine, but when deploying the project to Azure it failed and show error:
"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Can you please advise what can be problem? Should i setup anything in Azure for upload big files? Or how correct setup web.config(i can't find it in my project)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or how correct setup web.config(i can't find it in my project)?

When you deploy the .net core project to Azure, you could go to `https://xxxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net` and click `Debug console> CMD > site > wwwroot > web.config`. The `web.config` will be there. Then you could increase request limits to 200MB as below:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <!-- 100 MB in bytes -->
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="209715200" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Here is a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49520167/approach-for-archive-big-files-in-azure-storage/49525536#49525536) you could refer to.

Comment: Thank you, it's work. 
Also have another question by this solution, how to fix that web.config is rewriting after every deploy? 
Thanks

Comment: You could post another case and provided more details, so that I could help you more professional.